# CALCULAR HORAS TRANSCURRIDO MÁS DE 1 DÍAS EXCEL

Tags: excel, formulas

Buen día.

Por favor me ayudarían con la formula correcta para calcular el tiempo transcurrido en horas entre varios días.

Intente con la siguiente formula pero no me da el calculo correcto: =C2-D2+A2+B2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estamos de acuerdo que son más de 24 y 48 hrs.

¡Saludos y gracias!

Comment: ¡Gracias! Ambas formulas son correcta y si tiene razón Hermes no tenia sentido ya que estaba de madrugada y no pensaba con claridad. 

Les agradezco a ambos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que buscas puede hacerse así:

En primer lugar cambia la fórmula, que tal y como está no calcula bien, pon `=(C2+D2)-(A2+B2)`

Luego vete a formato de celda personalizado y busca el que pone `[h]:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

¿Cómo están guardadas las fechas y las horas? ¿En formato 'fecha' y 'hora' básicos, podemos asumir?

La fórmula que usas no tiene sentido, pero los números salen tan 'desviados', porque el formato 'hora' básico solo te va a mostrar desde 0 a 24. Pasa la columna de respuesta al formato 'hora' que marca como '37:30:55', o sea, que aparezcan los días como horas.

Y la fórmula que necesitas es =C1-A1+D1-B1. Esto te dará el total de horas.